# IntelliJ, Maven, Flexmojos - Failed to generate Flex compiler configuration file

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, artifactory, flexmojos

I'm running a multi-project build in IntelliJ setup with Flexmojos.

All of the flex modules have a common parent pom file which is downloaded from Artifactory. This dependency seems to be resolved properly but when I hit "Reimport All Maven Projects", or do changes to any child pom file, I get an error

```
Flexmojos Project Import
**Failed to generate Flex compiler configuration file.**
The pipe has been ended

Flexmojos Project Import
**Failed to generate Flex compiler configuration file.** 
exit code: 1
```

Globals (using maven 'defines' tag) defined in the parent pom are not visible in any child project and if I go into "Project Structure" there is

```
"Build configurations '[child artifactId]': additional compiler configuration file not found: [absolute path]"
```

, which is a symptom of the missing configuration files.

I think it is a settings (IntelliJ? Maven? Java?) issue because my colleague has the same code from SVN and does not have the same issue.

Any clues as to where to start looking?

EDIT:

Excerpt from idea.log

```
2013-08-13 16:35:34,213 [1978178]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Generating flex configs pathToBundledJar: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\plugins\flex\lib\flexmojos-flex-configs-generator-server.jar 
2013-08-13 16:35:34,214 [1978179]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Generate Flex Configs Task:"c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\plugins\flex\lib\flexmojos-flex-configs-generator-server.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\aether-api-0.9.0.M2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\aether-connector-wagon-0.9.0.M2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\aether-impl-0.9.0.M2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\aether-spi-0.9.0.M2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\asm-3.3.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\cdi-api-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\guava-11.0.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\jsr250-api-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\maven-aether-provider-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\maven-artifact-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\maven-compat-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\maven-core-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\maven-model-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\maven-model-builder-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\maven-plugin-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\maven-repository-metadata-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\maven-settings-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\maven-settings-builder-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M2a.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.0.0.M2a.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\plexus-cipher-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\plexus-interpolation-1.16.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\sisu-guice-3.1.3-no_aop.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\slf4j-simple-1.7.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\wagon-file-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\wagon-http-2.4-shaded.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\lib\wagon-provider-api-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.2.jar" com.intellij.flex.maven.GeneratorServer "C:\Program Files (x86)\maven-3.1.0\apache-maven-3.1.0\conf\settings.xml" " " C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\.m2\repository f D:/XXXXXXXXXXX/trunk/.idea/flexmojos 
2013-08-13 16:35:34,534 [1978499]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - The pipe has been ended 
java.io.IOException: The pipe has been ended
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:318)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:1816)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:716)
    at com.intellij.javascript.flex.maven.Flexmojos4GenerateConfigTask.writeWorkspaceMap(Flexmojos4GenerateConfigTask.java:379)
    at com.intellij.javascript.flex.maven.Flexmojos4GenerateConfigTask.runGeneratorServer(Flexmojos4GenerateConfigTask.java:198)
    at com.intellij.javascript.flex.maven.Flexmojos4GenerateConfigTask.perform(Flexmojos4GenerateConfigTask.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$100(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:28)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$2.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil$9.run(MavenUtil.java:433)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)
2013-08-13 16:35:34,536 [1978501]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4  Build #IU-129.713 
2013-08-13 16:35:34,536 [1978501]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 1.7.0_25 
2013-08-13 16:35:34,536 [1978501]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2013-08-13 16:35:34,536 [1978501]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2013-08-13 16:35:34,536 [1978501]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Windows 7 
2013-08-13 16:35:34,536 [1978501]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: SaveAll 
2013-08-13 16:35:34,537 [1978502]   WARN -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Generating flex configs exited with exit code 1 
2013-08-13 16:35:34,537 [1978502]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Generating flex configs out:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSession

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)

    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)

    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)

    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)

    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystemSession

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

    ... 6 more

Exception in thread "main"  
2013-08-13 16:35:35,036 [1979001]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Generating flex configs took 824 ms: 0 min 0sec
```

EDIT:
A typical child pom file has no build tag, it is supposed to inherit it from the base pom, they still have packaging 'swc' though.

Base pom has:

```
<flexmojos.version>4.2-beta</flexmojos.version>
<playerglobal.version>11.0</playerglobal.version>
<flexunit.version>4.1.0.8</flexunit.version>
<flex.sdk.version>4.5.1.21328</flex.sdk.version>
<flexpmd.version>1.2</flexpmd.version>
```

The full base pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.XXXXXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Toolbox - Config</name>

    <properties>

        <build.debug>false</build.debug>
        <swf.version>13</swf.version>

        <flex.flashPlayer.command>C:\FlashPlayer.exe</flex.flashPlayer.command>
        <flexmojos.version>4.2-beta</flexmojos.version>
        <playerglobal.version>11.0</playerglobal.version>
        <flexunit.version>4.1.0.8</flexunit.version>
        <flex.sdk.version>4.5.1.21328</flex.sdk.version>
        <flexpmd.version>1.2</flexpmd.version>

        <path.source>src</path.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:XXXXXX</connection>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${path.source}</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
                <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${flexmojos.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <swfVersion>${swf.version}</swfVersion>
                    <compilerWarnings>
                        <warn-no-constructor>false</warn-no-constructor>
                    </compilerWarnings>
                    <dumpConfigAttach>false</dumpConfigAttach>
                    <verboseStacktraces>${build.debug}</verboseStacktraces>
                    <debug>${build.debug}</debug>
                    <!--<coverage>${build.debug}</coverage>-->
                    <defines>
                        <property>
                            <name>CONFIG::debug</name>
                            <value>${build.debug}</value>
                        </property>
                    </defines>
                    <storepass>true</storepass>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>${flex.sdk.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.apparat</groupId>
                <artifactId>apparat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-RC9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tdsi-package</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>tdsi</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <alchemyExpansion>false</alchemyExpansion>
                    <inlineExpansion>true</inlineExpansion>
                    <macroExpansion>true</macroExpansion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.adobe.ac</groupId>
                <artifactId>flex-pmd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${flexpmd.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ruleSet>../../pmd-ruleset.xml</ruleSet>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.adobe.ac</groupId>
                <artifactId>flex-pmd-cpd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${flexpmd.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <minimumTokenCount>50</minimumTokenCount>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.adobe.ac</groupId>
                <artifactId>flex-pmd-metrics-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${flexpmd.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>debug</id>
            <properties>
                <build.debug>true</build.debug>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshot</id>
            <name>XXXXX</name>
            <url>XXXXXX</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>release</id>
            <name>XXXXXX</name>
            <url>XXXXXX</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>flex-mojos-plugin-repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>XXXXX</id>
            <url>XXXXXXX</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>flexpmd.opensource.adobe</id>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <name>FlexPMD repository on opensource.adobe.com</name>
            <url>http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flexpmd/maven-repository/release/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>XXXXX</id>
            <url>XXXXXX</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>flex-mojos-plugin-repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Please can you attach your idea.log? Your .pom files would be helpful as well. What is your flexmojos version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is bug due to "The switch in the core from Sonatype Aether to Eclipse Aether." since maven 3.1. Please watch&vote http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112107.

Answer (score 4):

I just hit the same problem. The java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSession is the issue and generated when you configure Intellij to use Maven v3.1.0 which doesn't include this library. Roll back to using Maven 3.0.5 with your flexmojos project to get this working.

Comment: I rolled back to 3.0.5 and now it seems fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the Flex Maven plug-in no longer generates the additional configuration file by default.  I'm not sure if that is a Flex or a Maven thing.  The easier solution I found is to tell the plug-in to generate the configuration file with the **configurationReport** flag:

```
mvn clean install -DconfigurationReport=true
```

This works with Maven 3.5.2.

I hope no one else in the world is still using Flex, and no one ever needs this information again.  I should change my title to either Senior Code Janitor or Senior Software Necromancer.

Comment: If you use Intellij, you need to disable the "doclint-java8-disable" profile, as well.